# Issue with @HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have following piece of code inside an angular component and works as expected:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onClick(event) {
 if(!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
  console.log("clicked outside");
  // code to close the component
 }
}
```

But it causes me an issue. My requirement is to open the component when user clicks on a text and close it when user clicks outside the component. Issue is that as text is outside the component, so clicking on it invokes above method and 'if' condition is satisfied , and hence component is closed immediately.

Comment: can you post  your child and parent component , will have to look into component layout

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit here? I am not well versed in angular.

Comment: I don't see the component code here but I am going to do my guesswork.
When the user clicks on the text set a flag to true and in the click hotlistener  check if the flag is true along with the event target then accordingly take action. If both condition meets then open a component else close the component.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
@HostListener("click", ["$event"])
```

There is no

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
```

Comment: why wouldn't there be `document:click`?